# Openshift instructions for adding node using scaleup.yml are unclear

Tags: ansible, openshift-origin

Instructions at https://docs.openshift.org/latest/install_config/install/advanced_install.html#adding-nodes-advanced for adding a node to an existing cluster in step 4 refer to this command:

```
ansible-playbook [-i /path/to/file] /usr/share/ansible/openshift-ansible/playbooks/byo/openshift-cluster/scaleup.yml
```

However, the latest openshift-ansible download does not have this file under the playbooks directory:

```
[root@jpr4042 ansible]# find . -name scaleup.yml
./openshift-ansible-master/playbooks/byo/openshift-master/scaleup.yml
./openshift-ansible-master/playbooks/byo/openshift-node/scaleup.yml
./openshift-ansible-master/playbooks/aws/openshift-cluster/scaleup.yml
./openshift-ansible-master/playbooks/common/openshift-master/scaleup.yml
./openshift-ansible-master/playbooks/common/openshift-node/scaleup.yml
```

With five similarly named options, I do not know how to proceed from here.

Thanks for any clarity you can provide!

Comment: Are you talking about bringing up a node in your own private cluster?

Comment: Exactly.  This is for an Openshift Origin cluster my company is using internally.